# Can I install libXcomposite.so without the root permission?

Tags: centos, x11, software-installation, libraries, non-root-user

I got this error when I execute dropbox on CentOS.

> ImportError: libXcomposite.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I don't have a root account.

Output of `uname -a`:

> Linux version 2.6.18-308.24.1.el5 (mockbuild@builder17.centos.org) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)) #1 SMP Tue Dec 4 17:43:34 EST 2012

Comment: Which is it: Ubuntu or Arch? The easiest way would be to ask your sysadmin to install that library.

Comment: Linux version 2.6.18-308.24.1.el5 (mockbuild@builder17.centos.org) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)) #1 SMP Tue Dec 4 17:43:34 EST 2012

Comment: How did you installed dropbox?

Comment: @Braiam, I followed the official instruction, wget the .tar.gz and extract to ~/.dropbox-dist. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I copied /usr/lib64/libX* to .dropbox-dist. Now the dropbox works in spite of some warnings about dbus.

```
process 21181: D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; failed to read machine uuid: Failed to open "/var/lib/dbus/machine-id": No such file or directory
See the manual page for dbus-uuidgen to correct this issue.
```

Anyhow, it works.